# Table border disappears when viewing?

Tags: tables, pdf

I've noticed lately that depending on what zoom level I'm viewing my document in Adobe Acrobat, my table borders will disappear and come back.

For example, here is a table in my most recent homework seen at 125% zoom:
[image: 125 percent zoom]

Here is the same document, now viewed at 150% zoom:
[image: 150 percent zoom]

I write my documents in Overleaf, and it happens no matter which machine I'm on (school and home).  I guess in the grand scheme of things it's no big deal, but it does bother me to think my documents may not be displaying as I want them to on the receiving if the person viewing it changes their zoom.

Any ideas?

Comment: +1! I have the same problem. This is probably a pdf-viewer problem, not a LaTeX one, but I hope someone knows how to solve it, it annoys me as well!

Comment: It is a problem with the viewer. Increase the width of the lines with something like `\arrayrulewidth=1pt` to circumvent this.

Comment: As @CarLaTeX has noted, what you've encountered is an issue with Acrobat and other pdf viewers, *not* with LaTeX. At a deeper level, though, you should rethink your approach to designing this table: Why are you using both black horizontal lines *and* color highlighting to denote the header row? Choose one or the other method, *but not both*. Then, start solving other (and in my view more troublesome) layout issues, such as the fat that the numbers in the data columns are currently centered instead of being aligned on the (implied) decimal markers.

Comment: Thank you, @Arzigoglu, I appreciate your suggestion.  I'll give it a try.